# What's the equivalent command of "wmic memlogical" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I'm trying to use `wmic memlogical` in Windows 7 but it says:

> memlogical - Alias not found

What's the equivalent command for Windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The aliases are a bit different in Windows 7 - *memlogical* doesn't exist. Here's how to get the same information in Windows 7:

**Total Physical Memory**

```
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```

**Available Physical Memory**

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
```

**Virtual Memory Max Size**

```
wmic OS get TotalVirtualMemorySize
```

**Virtual Memory Available**

```
wmic OS get FreeVirtualMemory
```

---

You can combine them as follows into one command:

```
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory && wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVirtualMemorySize,FreeVirtualMemory
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i wanted it in one command itself.. I also found the solution, which works perfectly for me `systeminfo | findstr "Memory"`

Answer (score 3):

I got one working..

```
systeminfo | findstr "Memory"
```

Comment: systeminfo is bad approach as it output localized according to Windows lang edition...

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say, but I'm assuming you're looking for an equivalent wmic command. (Rather than equivalent C function.) This is more of a system administration question rather than a programming question.

[The documentation for Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) explains where all the pieces of information got moved to.